# Vuex get data via slim (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

How to transfer data if I receive an array via Slim?

```
regions-list :region=@regions
```

`regions-list` - my component vue

`:region` - array with items

`@regions` - variable with items from backend

Im new with `vuex`, i think, i need something like this, but don’t know how to convey array with items

[image]

Comment: Will you be pulling data through the Api? Or do you just want to pass data to the Vue component (and then to vuex) from the Slim template?

Comment: @grovskiy If possible, i preffer second solution. But dont know how to convey (maybe need to export/import?) . In my ```vue component``` i already have ```props``` with ```region: []```

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54231287/8627079) can help you?

Comment: Let me know if you need an answer with Vuex, as I understood the question differently from the beginning and started writing the answer, but decided to clarify.

Comment: @grovskiy Unfortunately, this option does not fit, as it seemed to me. I know how to transfer from slim template to vue, but how work with vuex :\

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44373414/8627079)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the message about vuex. If there are no problems with receiving data, then I will add the answer that I prepared earlier.

Answer (score 1):

### This is how you can organize the work of Vuex

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    reactions: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    setReactions(state, segment) {
      state.reactions = segment;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async loadReactions({ commit }) {
      try {
        const reactions = '... response/request';

        commit('setReactions', reactions); // Here we use mutation to put new data into state.
      } catch (e) {
        // ...
      }
    },
  },
});
```

In your component vue regions-list

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ reactions }}</div> <!-- Here you can display and look at the content -->
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: 'RegionsList',
    computed: {
      ...mapState(['reactions']), // This is get the state
    },
    created() {
      this.loadReactions(); // Here you perform a function that receives data and puts it in state
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['loadReactions']),
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```